# Basic Weight Questions with HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

1. Do weights assigned to servers only effect the balance within that particular backend?
2. When implementing weights for the first time, if I give all the servers in a backend the same number, would that be the same as before when there we no weights?
3. How do I calculate just how much traffic I am shiffting by adjust weights by certain amounts. For example:

```
    server web1 10.10.10.10 weight 100
    server web2 10.10.10.11 weight 100
    server web3 10.10.10.12 weight 90
    server web4 10.10.10.13 weight 90
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. It should be.
2. Yes.

   From haproxy [config](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt).
   The "weight" parameter is used to adjust the server's weight relative to
   other servers. All servers will receive a load proportional to their weight
   relative to the sum of all weights, so the higher the weight, the higher the
   load. The default weight is 1, and the maximal value is 256.
3. It should be proportional as stated in 2.